# How to create a route in Laravel with GET query parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do I create a route in Laravel with GET query parameters.

For example consider:

```
Route::get('test?a={a}&b={b}', function ($a, $b) {
    dump($a);
    dump($b);
    dd("DONE!");
})->name('foo');
```

Now if I navigate to: `/test?a=5&b=10`, then I get a 404 error!

However, I am able to create URL's for it. e.g.

```
route('foo', [5, 10,]); // return "http://homestead.app/test?a=5&b=10"
```

Another issue I have is that generating URLs does not `url_encode` query parameters.

For example:

```
route('foo', [5, '&c=10',]); // return "http://homestead.app/test?a=5&b=&c=10"
```

I want it to return:

```
"http://homestead.app/test?a=5&b=%26c%3D10"
```

Therefore my question is how do I create a route in Laravel involving GET query parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change route to:

```
Route::get('test', function () { ... });
```

Then add parameters as an associative array:

```
route('foo', [
    'a' => '5', 
    'b' => '&c=10'
]);
```

Get parameters in a controller with:

```
$a = request('a');
$b = request('b');
```

Comment: I've updated the code, I'm afraid you'll have to get rid of parameters in the route definition.

Comment: I' making an edit to your code. I think you almost had it.

Comment: You basically could have just used an associative array instead of using html entities

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. )